# where i can find allwinner library for eagle

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, design, eaglecad, library

I work in a project using Allwinner a10 CPU and eagle software i did't find the library I already tried to searched in google and github many time for Allwinner a10 library for eagle software but I did't find any thing where i can find this library ?

Comment: Why not make the part yourself using the datasheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find it either, but if you manage to find an Eagle project which has the part you want then you can export it to a library.

Here's an open-source project that includes the A10 CPU:-

[A10-OLinuXino-LIME](https://www.olimex.com/Products/OLinuXino/A10/A10-OLinuXino-LIME/open-source-hardware)

Answer (score 0):

As Bruce said you can get it from an existing Eagle file like the one in [A10 OLinuXino project](https://www.olimex.com/Products/OLinuXino/A10/A10-OLinuXino-LIME/open-source-hardware).

You can then either extract the lbr using `exp-lbr.ulp` or you can copy it using the `GROUP` and `COPY` commands in the OLinuXino schematic and then `PASTE` command in your schematic.

You can get it from here as well http://wp.me/p2D6cb-Tz